# How to convey where a client is in your process?

Tags: client, process

In client work, you present the high level stages that you take them through.

Do you use an additional artifact to show them (during the project) that you are at a given phase, and here are the deliverables, and dependencies that the subsequent phases will use?

I'm looking for any examples you may have used or seen, and was curious if anyone had seen an infographic that encapsulated this effectively.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to convey the current status of the project to a client, or convey the client's own role in a project to a client?

Comment: I imagine that a client would be involved in most phases of the project (at least to sign off on things) both directly and indirectly, so it is probably not necessarily to show this unless there are many different parties involved. You may just show the input and output for each phase of the project as it relates to you and the client.

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately cant present screen shots of the the presentations due to NDA reasons,but I usually partially color the phase to demonstrate how much as been done eg:[image]

Comment: Understand about the confidentiality, but yeah this was my first thought, only a little more magnified to show that we are in this distinct phase, and here are the deliverables we are working toward.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little simplistic, but this reminded me of Domino's Pizza Tracker: [image: Domino's Pizza Tracker]

It doesn't really address the deliverables and dependencies directly, but with pizza it's a little easier to figure out ("pizza needs to be prepped before it's baked. The outcome of a prepped pizza is dough and toppings ready to go into the oven", etc).

The progress within the stage is shown simply by which phase/number is shaded (animated - phase 3 in this picture). The rough estimate of how long each phase will take is conveyed by the size of the section. As a user, I always wanted to know how far along within each stage it was, but I can understand why they can't do that with pizza. It's still a very cool feature. Plus, pizza. Mmmmmm.

Comment: GREAT example. Big, simple. thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how technical they are, I think something similar to a Gantt chart is great for showing the timeline and dependencies of a project. You can apply the visual styling in the same way that other people have suggested. The important thing is to be able to highlight the information of interest to the client, so make sure whatever you present they can understand it clearly then you won't have any problems.